# Does using a DH fork reduced to 150mm (6") make sense on an ebike?

Tags: fork, electric-bike, downhill

I recently found out that you can apparently reduce the travel of 8" DH forks such as Fox 40 to 6". This raises the question: would it make sense to do this for ebikes? I like dual-crown forks because they are stiffer and heavier and somehow seem more suited for an ebike, yet I don't see this approach in the wild as most people seem to be happy with single-crown fork such as Fox 34 or Fox 36.

Comment: Downhill bikes are mostly weights with some passing resemblance to bicycles.   What part of long travel suspension would be of benefit on your ebike riding ?

Comment: A 150 mm fork is considered to be "all mountain" (AM). Given the rigors of electric bike, I would say for an AM-application one would need an "enduro" fork (180 mm) reduced down to 150mm or so. Of course, more is not less, and going with 200 mm won't kill you. The reasoning is exactly the same as with non-assisted bikes - you can ride bigger stuff is you are ready to pay the weight and price penalty.

Comment: To be clear, are you taking about a proper electric *mountain* bike, or just a general purpose electric bike with front suspension? And if so what sort of mountain bike? Many e-bikes seem to be built as hybrids with low travel front suspension

Comment: @ChrisH I'm mainly talking about e-mtbs though if an ordinary ebike frame is designed for 150mm then I'm including those too because why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eBike manufacturers seem to think that single crown forks are strong and durable enough. Double crown forks are likely too heavy and overbuilt for use on an eBike.

Comment: Well yeah the question isn't if the fork is strong enough, but would it work and are there any caveats?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk I could rephrase the answer: yes it would work but there is no point because it adds extra weight that isn’t needed to get the necessary strength.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done? Yeah, sure. Why? Depends.

Depending on how the fork works on the inside, reducing the travel is pretty easy. You need spacers and sometimes a small spring.

What are the caveats? Well, less travel for one and a reduced chamber on the inside. If your fork suspension is by air, then well my friend you will have to tune the pressure pumped in the fork, as it will compress way faster than before. On some cases you will need to take a little bit of fork oil out, so you won't get hydro bottom the fork. Also you'll be surprised how much the weight balance would shift with a heavier fork.

The ride I've seen with eMtbs is like softcore enduro. They appeal to me in the sense that you don't a truck on a lift and you can ride longer. But you pay the weight penalty and the autonomy.

I was a Downhill Riders back in the day and let me tell you I do like those double crown forks, I feel more confident riding them but the materials used to build bikes nowdays are amazing, super strong and for most riding is OK.

If you ride like Josh Bender, I believe that Avalanche Suspension are still on the market.